# Using Linq on MembershipUserCollection

Tags: c#, linq, membership-provider

I have this code which gives me a list of all the users by using my membership provider.

```
        var users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
        var usernames = new List<string>();
        foreach(MembershipUser m in users)
            usernames.Add(m.UserName);
```

I thought there should be an easier way to do this by using LINQ, but I can't seem to use LINQ on a MembershipUserCollection

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Because MembershipUserCollection only implements `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<MembershipUser>`, you need to use the Linq extension method [Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) then then use other Linq extension methods:

```
Membership.GetAllUsers ().Cast<MembershipUser> ().Select (m => m.UserName);
```

Comment: I got the message "Evaluation time out" when sorting 30,000 records

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use LINQ, if you use the `Cast<T>()` method on it first.

Like this:

```
var usernames = Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>().Select(x => x.UserName).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally an alternative to explicit casting is to use

```
OfType<MembershipUser>
```

so you have

```
var userList = Membership.GetAllUsers().OfType<MembershipUser>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this piece of code to create a generic list of Members:

```
List<Member> memberList = new List<Member>();
foreach (MembershipUser membershipUser in members)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(membershipUser.ProviderUserKey);
    memberList.Add(new Member(id));
}
```